# In a ring $ab=ba=1$ and $ac=0\Rightarrow c=0\,$ [so fields are damains]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity. Suppose that there exist $a, b, c \in R$ such that $ab = ba = 1$ and $ac = 0$. Show that $c = 0$.

Since $ac=0$, we have $ab+ac=1$. So $a(b+c)=1$. Does this directly imply that $b+c=b$ and therefore $c=0$? I think that the fact that $ab = ba = 1$ matters, but I can't see what to do with it.

I know this exercise might be trivial for many, but it is my first encounter with rings and there are details that escape me.

Comment: $b+c=ba(b+c)=b$

Comment: FYI,  what this exercise shows you is that units (Things with inverses) cannot be zero divisors (Things that aren't 0 that can multiply by another non-zero to get 0)

Comment: @Alan Oh, I see. Your comment has been very illustrative. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a(b + c) = ab$ does not directly imply that $b + c = b$: $a$ could have several different right inverses (although it can't if $a$ has a left inverse). A quicker way of solving the problem is just to use the given equation $ba = 1$ thus: if $ac = 0$, you have:

$$c = 1\cdot c = (ba)c = b(ac) = b\cdot 0 = 0$$

So this a bit of a trick question: you don't need the assumption that $ab = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

$ac=0$ implies $0=b(ac)=(ba)c=c$.

Answer (score 1):

In any ring (or monoid): **(left) invertible elements are always (left) cancellable.** As usual, we can cancel $\,a\,$ by scaling the equation by its (left) inverse $\,b,\,$ just as in fields like $\,\Bbb Q,\,\Bbb R,\,\Bbb C,\,$ i.e.

$$\underbrace{\color{#c00}b\times (\color{#c00}ac = \color{#c00}ad)}_{\!\!\textstyle {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{ba=1}}\,\Rightarrow\, c = d\qquad $$

OP is the special case $\,d = 0,\,$ i.e. cancel $\,a\,$ from $\, ac = a\:\!0\,\Rightarrow\, c=0.\,$ In particular this implies that **a field is an integral domain** .